# c++ include guards don't work, error

Tags: c++, header, include

When I compile this code, i get an error "Error LNK2005 "int a" (?a@@3HA) already defined in file.obj
code:
main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

file.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
void function()
{

}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER
int a;
#endif
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Include guards don't do what you appear to think they do. They prevent multiple definition errors in a header file in a single translation unit, not in the entire program. Put the definition of `a` in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include guards guard from a header file being included twice in a single file but here you have two different files. My advice is not to define any variables in header files. Instead declare them as `extern` and define them in a separate cpp file where you include you header file. This way you will have only one definition but you will have them declared where you use them.

Answer (score 0):

In your header file you have

```
 Int a;
```

Wherever include that header file there is a global variable `a`

Then you have two versions of `a` in the  object  files.

Get to linking. AARGH the linker does not know what to do to resolve it.

Solution remove `int a`  from the header file. Use extern if you must. But best thing is not to have globals